# 1回だけQRコードを読み取りたい

Tags: swift, swift2, qr-code

### やりたいこと

タイトルの通り、1度だけQRコードを読み取り処理を行いたいのですが
リーダの範囲にQRコードがあるかぎり連続で読み込んでしまい処理がうまく行きません。
1度読み込み結果が出た際に読み込みを止めたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

---

### コード

```
class QRCodeReaderVC: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var mySession: AVCaptureSession! = AVCaptureSession()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        do {
            let myVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: myDevice)
            mySession.addInput(myVideoInput)
        } catch {}

        let myMetadataOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput! = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        ...

        mySession.startRunning()

    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if metadataObjects.count > 0 {
            let qrData: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject  = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondView") as! SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QRコードの読み込みが成功したのを確認したら、`AVCaptureSession.stopRunning()`（例のコードでは`mySession.stopRunning()`）を呼んでキャプチャセッションを停止する、

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if metadataObjects.count > 0 {
        let qrData: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject  = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        mySession.stopRunning() // 読み込めたらキャプチャセッションを停止する

        let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondView") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

または`isReaderEnabled`のようなフラグを導入してフラグが`true`の時のみデリゲートで処理をして、それ以外の時はQRコードを読み込んでも処理をスキップする、という方法もあります。

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    guard isReaderEnabled else { // フラグがtrueの場合だけ処理をする
        return
    }

    if metadataObjects.count > 0 {
        let qrData: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject  = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        isReaderEnabled = false // 読み込めたらフラグをオフにする

        let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondView") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```